# Create appointments in Outlook calenders of employees using C# and Exchange 2019

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I can't show any code here yet, because i'm still analyzing if it is possible to realize this.

In our company we have a virtual system to make and manage leave applications. I should now check if it would be possible to enter an approved vacation in the Outlook calendar of the applicant.

I would need a central solution which remotely accesses the calendar and enters the appointments.  We currently use the on premise solution of Mircosoft Exchange 2019 and Office 365.

During my research I came across EWS but it seems that Exchange 2019 does not support it anymore. Is there possibly another solution which I could use? Basically I would like to realize a solution with C# but I would also be able to realize a Powershell or Java solution. But most of the time I did not find a real solution.

Most of the time the examples are always local on the machines or using an older Exchange Server like 2013. I haven't found reliable information for 2019 yet. I hope someone here can help me or give me a hint. Or it would also be helpful to say if it is not possible.

Best regards!

---

I am currently working on a solution. I will post the code when I am successfull!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did choose a little bit different approach but I was able to make it fully work. I now can create events and delete them if needed.

```
    public void UpdateCalender()
    {
        ExchangeService Service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
        Uri Url = new Uri("https://localmaildomain.sys/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        Service.Url =  Url;
        Service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("service_user","service_password");

        Folder inboxFolder = Folder.Bind(Service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, Temp.UserMail));

        foreach (var entry in Temp.Positions)
        {
            if (!entry.Storno)
            {
                try
                {
                    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(Service);
                    appointment.Subject = $"Urlaub/Vacation ({entry.Type})";
                    appointment.Body = $"{entry.Comment}";
                    appointment.IsAllDayEvent = true;
                    appointment.Start = entry.Date.AddSeconds(1);
                    appointment.End = entry.Date.AddSeconds(1);
                    appointment.LegacyFreeBusyStatus = LegacyFreeBusyStatus.OOF;
                    appointment.Save(inboxFolder.Id, SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Calender item could not be created! Exception: {Ex.ToString()}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CalendarView view = new CalendarView(entry.Date, entry.Date);
                FindItemsResults<Appointment> results = Service.FindAppointments(inboxFolder.Id,view);

                foreach (var appointment in results)
                {
                    if (appointment.Subject == $"Urlaub/Vacation ({entry.Type})" && appointment.Start == entry.Date)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            appointment.Delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems);
                        }
                        catch(Exception Ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Calender item could not be deleted! Exception: {Ex.ToString()}");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But this doesnt work with Exchange 2019, how can it be a solution to your question? However im trying to get a response, I'll always get an exception. "The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML."

Comment: Is there any way in which we can use any other way of authentication other than `Service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("service_user","service_password");` because with this meathod we'll have to hardcode email and password.

There must be an other way where we can use previous authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2019 fully supports EWS.

EWS is still the preferred API to access Exchange, even if Microsoft is not adding any new features to it.

ON the client side, you can use Outlook Object Model and its `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` methods. Once you have an instance of the `MAPIFolder` object, you can use `MAPIFolder.Items.Add` to create a new appointment.